# Getting Logits and Labels mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I'm trying to build a chatbot using the tutorial [link](https://handsonai.medium.com/build-a-chat-bot-from-scratch-using-python-and-tensorflow-fd189bcfae45)

The dataset the tutorial uses is no longer available so I did my own with chatgpt.

A snippet of the dataset:

```
How was your day? Amazing! Thanks for asking! Every day is a fantastic day!
Tell me about yourself. I'm the happiest chatbot around! Ready to spread positivity and joy!
What's your favorite hobby? I absolutely love spreading positivity and making people smile! It's the best hobby ever!
```

It always question answer per line.

My code is here:

```
# Load data
with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    raw_data = f.read()

# Preprocess data
def preprocess(data):
    # Tokenize data
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(data)
    
    # Lowercase all words
    tokens = [word.lower() for word in tokens]
    
    # Remove stopwords and punctuation
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stop_words and word not in string.punctuation]
    
    # Lemmatize words
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens]
    
    return tokens

# Preprocess data
processed_data = [preprocess(qa) for qa in raw_data.split('\n')]


# Set parameters
vocab_size = 1280
embedding_dim = 64
max_length = 40
trunc_type='post'
padding_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"
training_size = len(processed_data)

# Create tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(processed_data)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

# Create sequences
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(processed_data)
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)



# Create training data
training_data = padded_sequences[:training_size]
training_labels = padded_sequences[:training_size]


# Build model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')
])

print(model.summary())

# Compile model

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm currently getting the error:

```
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,1280] and labels shape [1280]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_25724]
```

I already tried 'categorical_crossentropy' error function but I get a shape error again.

Tried a flatten layer but it didnt work as well.

Tried changing the way the training data and labels is done to:

```
labels = [sequence[1:] for sequence in padded_sequences]

# Create training data
training_data = padded_sequences[:training_size]
training_labels = labels[:training_size]

training_data = pad_sequences(training_data, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
training_labels = pad_sequences(training_labels, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)

training_data = np.array(training_data)
training_labels = np.array(training_labels)
```

But I get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!